# Reactjs - can't apply onClick to rendered component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, ecmascript-6

If I have the following code inside a React class component:

```
      <svg viewBox="-100 -100 600 500" id='renderName' >
            <Initial value={this.props.value.substring(0,1)} /> 
      </svg>
```

I seem to only be able to fire an onClick event from the container svg, and not from the 'Initial' component I'm rendering.

E.g.

```
      <svg viewBox="-100 -100 600 500" id='renderName' onClick={this._onButtonClick} >
```

^ Works

```
      <Initial value={this.props.value.substring(0,1)} onClick={this._onButtonClick} />
```

^ Doesn't work

Any idea why this could be? Is it something to do with 'onClick' being passed as a prop instead of calling the function?

As an update: `Initial` is being rendered within another component. It is on this component where there's a function I want to call with onClick.

Comment: What does `Initial` render?

Comment: Initial renders a basic <Text> element to put inside the SVG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Initial` in your code is a component, and not an element, so you should pass the `onClick` property this component gets to the actual element that it renders:

```
class Initial extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return <rect
                   ...
                   ...
                   onClick={this.props.onClick}
               />
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Currently 'Initial' is just a functional component, would it have to be class based for this to work? Will this actually fire the onClick event back to the component which references 'Initial'?

Comment: @Calibre, you are welcome. Please accept and vote it if its correct. Thanks!

Comment: I'll try it this evening. Is it possible to use the property in that way to call a function on the parent component? (I added a slight edit to the original question if that helps).

Comment: Yes, you can do it. What's important to understand is the differences between components and elements. All of the events are triggered on elements, not components. When you look at components you only pass a reference to the component from it's parent, and there you can use this reference as part of the event.